# Placeholder on input only displays in development environment, but does not display on production build in React

Tags: reactjs

The code below is a simple form that has some placeholder that for some reason only work in development (yarn react start) but when generating the build files and serving it or even hosting in a server, the placeholders are not showing anymore.

I have already tried to change the input time, change placeholder to placeHolder and all the imaginable things but the placeholders still don't work on production. Do you have any ideia here?

The code of the form below:

[Placeholder displaying on development](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unY9p.png)
[Placeholder does not displaying on production](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzmLS.png)

Form code:

```
                    <form>
                        <input type = "text" placeHolder = "Digite seu nome" className = "generalInput"/>
                        <input type = "text" placeHolder = "Digite seu email" className = "generalInput"/>
                        <input type = "text" placeHolder = "Digite a cotação que gostaria de sugerir" className = "generalInput"/> <br/> <br/>
                        <button type = "submit" className = "sendSuggestionButton">Enviar sugestão</button>
                    </form>
                </div
```

CSS code:

```
    border: 0;
    width: 80%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    text-indent: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    border-color: rgb(red, green, blue);
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #299e29;
}

.sendSuggestionButton {
    background-color: #4FE84F;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    margin-top: -20px;

}
```

Comment: can you please share you pacakge.json? since I tired your example and I change placeholder and all its work perfect in production mode: https://csb-7owic.netlify.app/

and this is code soruce: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-currying-7owic?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Sure! https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-northcutt-gwsm1?file=/package.json

Comment: Thanks, I see it's normal, but just for test, can you try to use react-app-rewired build nested react-scripts build

Comment: Also, may you need to try to remove wrapper for form, just to make sure theres nothing make error or override default attribute, for example, make it direct in app.jsx or create a new react app and put it direct like my attach in code sandbox